# Hibernate Tutorial - Receiving errors

Tags: hibernate, maven-2

I'm extremely new to Hibernate. I posted a question before and it turns out the actual tutorial has bugs in it.  But I thought I had straightened those things out.  Anyway I am [this part of the tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-firstapp-workingpersistence).  When I do everything as it states before and get up to this point where you execute the line of code that says:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.hibernate.tutorial.EventManager" -Dexec.args="store"
```

When I run that in cmd prompt inside of the correct folder: in my scenario the root folder is called test.  I get the following error:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb
```

I am using only Maven and Hibernate.  I am not using any IDE for this either.  If I dont already have a db is one created for me?

Apparently no driver is found for the hsqldb which doesn't make sense to me.

I've included a ss
[image]
[image]

Edit: Included the pom.xml
http://www.jamesendres.com/pom.xml

Edit 2: Included the entire project
http://www.jamesendres.com/test.rar

Comment: can you add an -X argument to mvn exec and make sure the classpath contains the hsql jar.

Comment: The classpath line is not visible. Can you update your question with the pom.xml and / or output of mvn dependency:tree

Comment: @gkamal Just added the pom.xml.  I'm not too familiar with mvn but I'll look for the output of the dependency:tree

Comment: Can you try running with  -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime. Also verify if the hsqldb jar is fine - the jar will be under user.home/.m2/repository/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.1

Comment: Yeah hsqldb is in the folder you specified but I still get the error.  I edited my post to include the link to my entire project.

Comment: It works for me - I downloaded the source - made 2 changes.  Changed slf4j-simple version from 1.5.8 to 1.6.1  and changed the connection.url to jdbc:hsqldb:hsql:mem.  Remember to run mvn compile -  before running mvn exec..  it doesn't compile automatically.  I think that is the root cause of all your troubles - the changes you were making were not getting picked up because you didn't do compile

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is the `hsqldb` is a ***plugin*** `dependency` and not a project `dependency`.  If so, you can either change the dependency appropriately or pass an [additional argument](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#includePluginDependencies) `-Dexec.includePluginDependencies=true` to `mvn exec:java`.

Comment: I tried that and I still get the same error.  I asked a friend and they said "you need to specify the driver for hibernate somewhere. probably a hibernate.properties file or a persistence.xml."

Answer (score 0):

You have register the driver when you use HSQL.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2262136/51782 or http://www.willamaze.eu/2009/02/running-hsqldb-in-process-no-suitable-driver-found/.

Comment: Is there any way to have Maven do this?  I don't understand why the tutorial would have us do something outside of the scope of the tutorial.  I also actually did try to add the try catch to the EventManager.java file but I still had no luck.

Comment: The suggested code change is to add `Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");` and not the try-catch block.  And no, Maven won't do this for you.  As for why the tutorial doesn't do this already -- I don't know.  As you mentioned in the post you've had to resolve other bugs in the tutorial.  You could try posting to Hibernate's own user forum (https://forum.hibernate.org/)