# SQLException: No suitableDriver found

Tags: tomcat, sqlexception

This is one of the most topics, but no other on stackoverflow fits.

My enviroment is a Tomcat 7 with a JNDI-DataSource defined in context.xml. When i start my Tomcat the following exception is thrown

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource' for connect URL 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/app;create=true'
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseExporter.<init>(DatabaseExporter.java:52)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:367)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:304)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:293)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:498)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1743)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
at com.opensolutions.openflow.persistence.DefaultEntityManagerStore.<init>(DefaultEntityManagerStore.java:20)
at com.opensolutions.openflow.servlet.ApplicationWebserviceServlet.initApplication(ApplicationWebserviceServlet.java:38)
at com.opensolutions.openflow.servlet.ApplicationWebserviceServlet.loadBus(ApplicationWebserviceServlet.java:27)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.init(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:71)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5033)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5317)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:289)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
... 37 more
```

Any solutions? I dont know. I tried so much, but nothing works.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using DerbyDB 10.9.1.0

Comment: Show us the definition of the DataSource, it seems you have configured the wrong *driver* class, because `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource` is not the name Derby's JDBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

This line in the stack trace is the key to solving the problem:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

Since the exception is thrown at `org.apache.tomcat...` it seems that you haven't placed your database driver in tomcat's `lib` directory (i.e. you are missing dependencies). The folder stores external dependencies that are needed by your applications and is located in `apache-tomcat-version/lib/`. You need to supply the driver to both your web application and tomcat server.

Also, have a look at these related quetions:

1. [JDBC/MSQL: No suitable driver found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146793/jdbc-msql-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost3306-mysql)
2. [Cause of No suitable driver found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160611/cause-of-no-suitable-driver-found-for)
3. [java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616898/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmicrosoftsqlserver)

---

**EDIT**

The problem is perhaps that the webapp doesn't have [access to the library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267953/managing-libraries-in-tomcat), Try adding the library in [tomcat-home-folder/common/lib](http://javahowto.blogspot.co.uk/2007/01/tomcat-commonlib-vs-sharedlib.html). I tried this and tomcat7 did not have a common folder, so I would instead placed the library into webapp/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Look at this: http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/1711/tomcatlib.png I am also using maven and in my webapp-war-folder is also this JDBC Class Driver :( I checked my URL its like: 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1521/app;create=true' I dont know who i can solve this problem...i already read all topics you advised to me :(

Answer (score 0):

I had an incorrect jdbc url like this:

Wrong!

```
jdbc:jtds://myserver:port;databaseName=abc
```

Correct:

```
jdbc://myserver:port;databaseName=abc
```

(removed the `jtds:` part...)

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the jdbc driver's path?
When you use Oracle Database, you need to set the jar file (jdbc driver) path to "CLASSPATH".