# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver on tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, spring, oracle, tomcat, jdbc

I'm getting an exception when i start application on tomcat on eclipse.

Version

```
ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar    
apache-tomcat-8.5.31
jdk-8u172-windows-x64
```

Spring config

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
     <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
     <property name="url" value="${database.connection.url}" />
     <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
     <property name="password" value="${database.pwd}" />
     <property name="initialSize" value="${database.pool.initialSize}" />
     <property name="maxTotal" value="${database.pool.maxTotal}" />
     <property name="maxIdle" value="${database.pool.maxIdle}" />
     <property name="minIdle" value="${database.pool.minIdle}" />
     <property name="maxWaitMillis" value="${database.pool.maxWaitMillis}" />
</bean>
```

properties

```
database.user=dev
database.pwd=dev
database.connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin@X.X.X.X:1521:DATABASE
```

The exception :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:oracle:thin@X.X.X.X:1521:DATABASE'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2161)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2152)
```

I tried to put the driver jar on lib folder of tomcat but same error

I'm getting the error also on Wildfly 10.1.

Comment: Give a try using: '"jdbc:oracle:thin@//X.X.X.X:1521/DATABASE"

Comment: same problem with both oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver and oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Comment: You have a typo in your url, you are missing a colon (`:`) after `thin`. It should be `jdbc:oracle:thin:@X.X.X.X:1521:DATABASE`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054105/url-string-format-for-connecting-to-oracle-database-with-jdbc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cause of No suitable driver found for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160611/cause-of-no-suitable-driver-found-for)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel 
Thanks, it worked fine after adding a colon (:)

Answer (score -1):

I see you are referring to wrong Package inside Oracle 7 jar.
Use OracleDriver class name as follows `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

```xml
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
```

You can always open the jar and locate the class for OracleDriver: [image]

Please refer to this image to see the OracleDriver class path

Comment: I'm getting the same error with *oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver* class

Comment: Other than ojdbc class i dont see any issue with your code. Can you confirm "database.connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin@X.X.X.X:1521:DATABASE "   DATABASE is a Servicename or SID? Please paste the exception again with updated Ojdbc class

Comment: DATABASE is SID

Comment: Can you paste the exception again

Comment: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:oracle:thin@X.X.X.X:1521:DATABASE'
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Comment: May i know your oracle version

Comment: mu oracle versuin is 12c
dialect config is org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect

Comment: This is incorrect advice, the driver to load is `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202653/difference-between-oracle-jdbc-driver-classes